# Accessing dependency injected class variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently injecting my eloquent models in my controllers like this:

```
class ComputerController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(User $user, Machine $machine, MachineType $machineType){
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->machine = $machine;
        $this->machineType = $machineType;
}
```

So I can access the models quickly with:

```
$this->machine->get();
```

But how to I access the properties such as validation rules that are stored in the class?

I used to use

```
Machine::$rules;
```

But using this method

```
$this->machine->$rules
```

Does not work. Is there a way to retrieve the rules array that is stored in the eloquent model?

This is my class as an example:

```
class Machine extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'machines';
public $timestamps = true;
protected $softDelete = true;

public static $rules = array(
    'computer_name' => 'required|min:2',
    'computer_user' => 'required',
    'computer_ip'   => 'ip'
);
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit:: Tried this according to Antonio just to test, still no avail, brings an error when I run it.
  [image]

Error:
  [image]

Comment: What error gives? Did you try, $this->machine->rules?

Comment: I'm not familiar with eloquent, but if you do need to get around the api, you could try php's ReflectionClass and ReflectionProperty classes:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php

Comment: @gonzalon I get this error with your suggestion:    Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\www.helpdesk.dev\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 211 and defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static variables, this should work fine:

```
$this->machine::$rules
```

EDIT:

Somehow using an object this way it doesn't work, but here's a workaround:

```
$machine = $this->machine;
dd($machine::$rules);
```

Comment: My array is static (EDIT: and public) in my eloquent model, but I get this error with your method: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Comment: Just edited with a workaround, but finding this odd. Will do a research to understand why it doesn't work directly...

Comment: That works, thanks! Dreamweaver still detects it as an error though... I can work with it. I'll definitely be keeping an eye on this though, and I'd definitely appreciate your research, thanks again!